# Why is title bar for phpstorm hidden for some windows?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, phpstorm

I'm running phpstorm on Ubuntu with Gnome. The title bar disappears for some of the projects, but not all of them. Phpstorm is the only program that has this issue. How do I fix it? I always want the title bar.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having this problem with Ubuntu MATE. The title bar disappears randomly. I might have a few projects open, and lose the title bar on one of them after a while.

It looks like the title bar vanishing is a known issue:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-337548/No-main-menu-on-simple-linux-with-Xvfb
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-341584/No-menu-bar-in-new-UI-over-X11
- Etc

Comment: And it seems like the bug is solved and that I only have to wait for next update. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With the help from [Alex answer](https://superuser.com/a/1822730/707055) I managed to solve it.

Note, that at the time you're reading this, it's likely not relevant anymore. The [bug is known and fixed](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-337548/No-main-menu-on-simple-linux-with-Xvfb) and will not be an issue in future versions.

But to fix it now, enter Settings. If you have the new UI enabled, just deselect "Merge main menu with window title" and restart. If you do not have the new UI enabled, enable it first.